# how to clean text data with dates like 'c1995', ~2001, 2014; to get just %yyyy

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd
text = [ "y1983 Clinic Hospital", ".2010 - wife; nightmares", " shx of TBI (1975)",
         "TSH okay in 2015", "Esophageal cancer, dx: 2013", "8mo in 2009\n", "2008 partial thyroidecto"]
        
d1 = df.str.extract(r'(?P<day>)(?P<month>)^[\D\s\.\. \- \~\: \; ]?(?P<year>\d{4})')

d1
result
    monthdayyear
466         1981
470         1983
497         2008
```

I am not able to find all date format in this %yyyy date format

Comment: assuming `df` a DataFrame, `df.str.extract` is not valid, is it rather a Series? Can you provide the definition?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are seeking to get the year from the given strings. If that's the case then you can do that using regex like below.

```
import re

text = [ "y1983 Clinic Hospital", ".2010 - wife; nightmares", " shx of TBI (1975)",
    "TSH okay in 2015", "Esophageal cancer, dx: 2013" ,"8mo in 2009\n", "2008 partial thyroidecto"]
    
regex = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"

for t in text:
    result = re.search(regex, t)
    print(result.group())
```

Comment: What of when I have the year like this 'wWhen 1998.

Comment: @paschal sorry but I didn't get you. can you explain again?

Comment: I mean, when the year appears in a text data like this 'wWhen 1998.' How can I use regex to clean and select only the year i.e. 1998?

Comment: have you tried my code? it'll work on your case as well.